# Make a single page webapplication crawlable for social networks (Facebook/Twitter/reddit)

Tags: javascript, facebook, backbone.js

I have a single page webapplication written in Backbone (backend is a Restful java api).
My problem is simple: I know how to make my website crawlable for google - but not for social networks.

Try that link on FB: http://eese.com/story/206875

It will just show you the standard meta description and not the actual content.

Is there a way to make my website crawlable for social networks? (Hope its not too broad - i would like to know a general concept to achieve this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from using the correct OpenGraph tags, you need to be able to serve a static version of your SPA.

Have a look at a pre-rendering solution like https://prerender.io/ This will present the crawlers a static version of your website.

Comment: I see. But i would need a mechanism to say: "Ok this is a user" and "ok this is a crawler". I know the escaped_fragment from google - but how does that work with other crawlers? How can i detect them?

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook links, I would suggest making sure you have proper OpenGraph tags in the `<meta>` section of your page, i.e.:

`<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Favorite News"/>`

Following Facebook's [Best Practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices) you can customize the description and other things that are shown when the page is posted to Facebook. [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started#opengraph) and other social networks use similar OpenGraph style tags as well.

Comment: That won't help entirely, because the site is rendered dynamically.

Comment: Thats what i also thought ;)